# getRowHeight() not working with rowModelType = 'infinite' with latest ag-grid version

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

I see this Note on ag-grid site:

> Changing the row height is only supported in the in memory row model. You cannot use variable row height when using virtual paging, viewport or enterprise row models. This is because these row models need to work out the position of rows that are not loaded and hence need to assume the row height is fixed.

But getRowHeight() was well supported in previous releases(7.x), so was wondering there must be some alternate way to achieve that.

I was using rowModelType='pagination' with previous versions of ag-grid. But Since rowModelType='pagination' is deprecaded, I replaced this with rowModelType='infinite'. 
But with this, the getRowHeight() is not working as mentioned in there website.

Is there an alternate way to achieve this.
My Grid Options:

```
var gridOptions = {
floatingFilter:true,
debug: true,
enableServerSideSorting: true,
enableServerSideFilter: true,
enableColResize: true,
rowSelection: 'single',
rowDeselection: true,
columnDefs: columnDefs,
rowModelType: 'infinite',
paginationPageSize: 10,
cacheOverflowSize: 2,
maxConcurrentDatasourceRequests: 2,
infiniteInitialRowCount: 1,
maxBlocksInCache: 2,
//rowHeight: 5,
getRowNodeId: function(item) {
    return item.id;
},
getRowHeight: function(params){
  return 300;
}
```

};

Here is My Plunkr where I tried to use getRowHeight() but it did not work.
https://plnkr.co/edit/P6fnVz4ud1A68khuqDtx?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do the code below after getting the data:

```
setRowsHeight(){
    let gridHeight = 0;

    this.gridOptions.api.forEachNode(node => {
        let rowHeight = this.gridOptions.getRowHeight(node);

        node.setRowHeight(rowHeight);
        node.setRowTop(gridHeight);

        gridHeight += rowHeight;
    });
    if (!gridHeight) {
        return;
    }

    let elements = this.el.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('ag-body-container');
    if (elements) {
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(elements[0], 'height', `${gridHeight}px`)
    }
}
```

I hope it will help you
for me it resolved the issue

Comment: I tried this, though it seems working initially, it did not work properly. On scrolling down, rows started to flicker. and I get warning 
 [Violation] 'requestAnimationFrame' handler took xx ms

Comment: OK..thanks your solution worked 90%. I needed to added one more extra gridOption property to avoid row flickering. gridOptions.rowBuffer = 1000 (a large value)

Answer (score 9):

`getRowHeight()` is not supported in infinite row model. **getRowHeight** only works with the **InMemoryRowModel**