# autoHeight with infinite rowModel in ag-Grid not working

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Is it possible to get autoHeight working for rows in ag-Grid community edition? I've seen plenty of examples for the 'serverSide' row model, and others, but this only exists in the enterprise edition, but not in the community edition.

Surely there has to be a way to work around this and get it to work in the community edition?

Comment: Please add more details about your use case. why exactly you need autoheight with  infinite rowModel ?

Comment: I suspect autoHeight doesn't work with `infinite` rowModel as hinted in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44827590/9449426

Comment: I've decided to write my own plain HTML table component instead, since I need to use the community edition of the grid. I don't actually need row-selection so a table will work OK.